# Sketching this likelihood function

Tags: statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

[image]

I am doing the question above and have some questions. The pdf of this the distribution is $\frac{1}{\theta}$ for $0\leq x\leq \theta$ and $0$ otherwise, correct? So the joint pdf will be $\frac{1}{\theta^n}$? So the likelihood function is $\frac{1}{\theta^n}$, but I am unsure how to sketch that since the graph changes for different n? Or am I supposed to use the log likelihood?

I am also given these hints:

[image]

But I don't understand why in the last hint it says we cannot have $\theta < 2$ . Any help? Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit more subtle than just being $1/\theta^n$ and the clue is exactly in the last hint. Imagine that $\theta=1$. That means you have a uniform distribution over the interval $[0,1]$. But your sample contains the value $x_2=2$. Can it really be drawn from such a distribution?

Comment: @Raskolnikov I see, that makes sense. When we sketch the likelihood function, is $\theta$ on the x-axis and $\textbf{x}$ on the y-axis? So the point of considering the range of both of these is for the sketch? Or is it L on the y-axis and theta on the x-axis?

Comment: No, you should only sketch a figure of the likelihood versus $\theta$. Just assume some set of values for the $\textbf{x}$. It's a sketch to get an idea of the likelihood distribution. However, you can add the values of the $\textbf{x}$ on your X-axis.

Comment: @polly Likelihood is a function of $\theta$; if you sketch $\mathcal{L}(\theta)$ obvious $\theta$ is on the x-axis and $\mathcal{L}$ is on the y-axis